# Log4j didn't working properly with DailyRollingFileAppender when shutdown web container

Tags: java, logging

I have a webapp using Tomcat and Log4j. I use DailyRollingFileAppender to roll over log file everyday.

```
log4j.appender.A.File=/tmp/log/service.log
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|[%t]|[%C.%M()<%L>] {%m}%n
```

Say at the time 2015-10-16 23:59:00, log4j is writing logs to `service.log`. when the next day comes, log4j successfully roll over the file. Now i have two files `service.log` and `service.log.2015-10-16`. The last modified time of `service.log.2015-10-16` is "2015-10-16 23:59:09". And log4j is writing log to the new file `service.log`. But with the help of `fuser`, i can see that the java process is using both files.

Say  i restarted tomcat say at "2015-10-16 07:00:00", the last modified time of `service.log.2015-10-16` becomes "2015-10-17 07:00:00". And the content of `service.log.2015-10-16` becomes the log between "2015-10-17 00:00:00" to "2015-10-17 07:00:00". i.e, i lost the log of 2015-10-16. The content of `service.log` is the log of after "2015-10-17 07:00:00".

I opened the debug mode of Log4j by using `-Dlog4j.configDebug`, but i didn't find any error.

I think the cause this problem is probably log4j does not shutdown properly. 
Can any one explain to me?

This is an excerpt of DailyRollingFileAppender.rollOver()

```
// close current file, and rename it to datedFilename
this.closeFile();

File target  = new File(scheduledFilename);
if (target.exists()) {
  target.delete();
}
File file = new File(fileName);
boolean result = file.renameTo(target);
if(result) {
  LogLog.debug(fileName +" -> "+ scheduledFilename);
} else {
  LogLog.error("Failed to rename ["+fileName+"] to ["+scheduledFilename+"].");
}
```